# Viewport issue on normal orientation mobile

Tags: android, css, mobile, orientation

[image: Click]

There is a viewport issue on vertical orientation of the mobile.As you can see,below the footer,there is a white space which fills the screen.If i turn the orientation on horizontal, the viewport works fine,same for tablets,desktop,etc..this issue persists only on vertical orientation of the mobile.Is there any way to fix this?

I already have this metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: what happens if you add **height=device-height,** into your content attr ?

Comment: Isn't that just because the page is not as high as the screen?

Comment: @MrLister , i already specified, that on the other devices,works just fine, even on mobile,the problem is present on the vertical orientation

Comment: @Alp , i tried it,but makes no difference , though it mess up my width viewport

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your code and run it on our own device(s).

Comment: provide your html and css, or make a fiddle so we can analyze your issue.

Comment: have you tried this `<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">` ?

Comment: @maioman , yes i did , no difference

Comment: make a test ; set `initial-scale=2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need use media queries:**

1. Start with your mobile (base) styles first in your CSS (This is typically a single column layout).
2. Then use media queries using min-width at progressively larger viewports breakpoints (This is where you would apply your grid styles).
3. Use each each larger min-width breakpoint to override the previous
   styles to provide an appropriate layout based on the viewport size.
4. Make sure to use the [`<meta name="viewport" />`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) tag in your html to ensure optimal mobile presentation.

Using Cascading min-width media queries will allow you to know exactly what properties are being applied based on the screen width and make troubleshooting your css easier.

**Edit - Added media query reference links:**

- [Media Query Logic](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)
- [7 Habits of Highly Effective Media Queries](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/)

**Mobile First Example - Single column on small screens and two columns larger with a border color change on even larger screens**

```css
div {box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;border:solid 1px red;}

@media only screen and (min-width:37.5em) {
   .half {
       float: left;
       margin: 0;
       width: 50%;
   }
   .row:after {
     content:"";
     display:table;
     clear:both;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:50em) {
   div {border:solid 1px green;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="half">Stuff 1</div>
        <div class="half">Stuff 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="half">Stuff 3</div>
        <div class="half">Stuff 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i hoped there could be another way of doing it ,than media queries .. a quicker one.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PetruLebada - It may not be as bad as you think. Your design is fairly simple and should work well as is on large phones and small tablets. So, you may be able to to place most of your grid based layout attributes, such as your column widths and floats, in a media query like `@media only screen and (min-width:48em)` and be almost done. I wish I could offer more advice but it is difficult without seeing the actual CSS that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the " marks make a difference but you could always try.

`<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport

**Edit 1**: Try working with Media Queries if that solves the problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Do some elements on the page, like the container/wrapper etc, have a fixed width? It could also be that your media queries aren't correct on the smaller screen sizes?

Comment: that white navigation bar from the top of the page is fixed,and i dont use media queries yet, until now i just made each element's size with vh and vw , and it works fine except this issue

Comment: @PetruLebada Can you please supply a fiddle so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 2):

> **Mobile browsers** handle orientation changes slightly differently. For example, Mobile Safari often just zooms the page when changing from portrait to landscape, instead of laying out the page as it would if originally loaded in landscape. If web developers want their scale settings to remain consistent when switching orientations on the iPhone, they must add a **maximum-scale value to prevent this zooming**, which has the sometimes-unwanted side effect of preventing users from zooming in:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

**[<kbd>More Info</kbd>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_width_and_screen_width)**

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try maximum-scale?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```